# Google Cloud : Outbound IP Address for GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-kubernetes-engine

I have the following setup:

- GKE running in a cloud project with ingress IP restriction
- Dataflow running in **another** project that needs to access the API exposed by GKE

Dataflow has variable number of workers and hence, I will have different IP address. Is there any way by which I can setup an outbound IP for all the dataflows (when they send a `REST` request) so that I can filter those requests out at GKE's end.

I have explored Cloud VPN but that might not work as I do not have control over GKE project. I just want an IP that I can provide to GKE load balancer to white list.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't really ask the other project owners to setup a VPC and create a firewall rule to allow only a specific tag (such as dataflow), then you could use a VM with a static external IP as a proxy to the Kubernetes cluster.

This is because you can not know up front what IPs will the Dataflow workers get, so indeed you will get workers within a very large IP range. I think using a specific network tag would be very helpful in this case, since all the Dataflow workers will get that tag.

Comment: As the dataflow and GKE belong to different cloud project, can I create a VPC that spans across more than one Google Cloud project?

Comment: If the Projects are within the same organization, you can use [Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc), but if they belong to different organizations, then you can do [VPC Network Peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering).